# Use Gradle plugin without adding to build.gradle?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

In Maven you can do `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to run the `eclipse` goal of the `maven-eclipse-plugin`. Is there a similar way to do this in Gradle? I'd like to run the plugin for my IDE of choice but I want my build script to remain "IDE-agnostic".

I don't want `apply plugin 'eclipse'` in my `build.gradle` file but want it to generate the Eclipse files it needs. This way users of IntelliJ won't need to swap it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than rely on the build tool to configure your IDE (who ever thought that was a good idea is beyond me), set up the IDE to understand and integrate with the build tool. Eclipse is specifically designed to share configuration in such a way that each person who checks out a project from source control gets the project configured correctly with a minimum of manual intervention. Gradle support is much newer and somewhat less mature than Ant or Maven, but it works. See the [Buildship project](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship), which allows you to point Eclipse at your existing Gradle-based project and import it as a *properly* configured Eclipse project, no need for hacks like `mvn eclipse:eclipse` (which is now deprecated/retired, by the way)